# Is accessing `data` properties via `wrapper.vm` the correct way, as per the docs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chai, vue-test-utils

How can I access a `data` property in a Vue test instance?

I see that you can access `props`, but there's no `data` equivalent. I can grab a data property by using something like `wrapper.vm.foo`, but I feel that there is another way of doing this that may fall more in the lines of the test framework.

**App.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          foo: 'bar'
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

**App.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe("App.vue", () => {

  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // use this to check the state of anything in the view
    wrapper = shallowMount(App)
  });

  it("Module has the expected data attribute", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.foo).to.equal('bar'); // passes

    expect(wrapper.foo).to.equal('bar'); // fails
    expect(wrapper.data('foo')).to.equal('bar'); // fails
    expect(wrapper.data().foo).to.equal('bar'); // fails
  });


  it('simple passing test', () => {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });


});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may be possible, but `.vm` is the correct way.

Example from the `vue-test-utils` [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#simulating-user-interaction):

```
it('button click should increment the count', () => {

  expect(wrapper.vm.count).toBe(0)
  const button = wrapper.find('button')
  button.trigger('click')

  // `wrapper.vm.count` it is!
  expect(wrapper.vm.count).toBe(1)

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying DevLime's answer a bit, I prefer to use wrapper.vm.$data instead of wrapper.vm as follows:

```
it('button click should increment the count', () => {

    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.count).toBe(0)
    const button = wrapper.find('button')
    button.trigger('click')

    // `wrapper.vm.$data.count` it is!
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.count).toBe(1)

})
```

It works fine with V2 of Vue test utils.

Comment: why do you prefer wrapper.vm.$data ??

Comment: @KickButtowski I am a bit new to Vue. So, for syntactical clarity, I use an extra "$data" so that I don't get confused when I read the code in the future. :)

I am not aware about the performance comparison among the 2 methods though.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling over this: `wrapper.vm.$data.count` seems to return `undefined` with Vue 3 and vue-test-utils 2. However, `wrapper.vm.count` seems to work fine.